# Bulk Geocoding Through HttpRequest

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, bing-maps

I'm researching ways to perform bulk geocoding through http request, and get the response back in JSON, XML, or anything pHp can handle on the server side.

The amount of address in a batch is in the hundreds. Each user of this mobile-web app will make one request (one batch) only if I can store the data on my own server once they're returned.

To sum it up for people looking to do similar things:

1. Google Map's term doesn't let you make too many requests
2. Openstreetmap's term doesn't allow heavy querying either
3. Bing...
4. TinyGeocoder...Does anyone knows the usage limit and batch capability of this?   (tinygeocoder.com)

I've come to Bing and see this under their terms:
(http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html)

(c) Exceed a total of 24 batch geocoding or file uploads with a maximum of 200,000 records each, using the Bing Spatial Data Services API, within any 24 hour period.

Can someone who's familiar with their API or geocoding in general tell me, Does that mean I can only make 24 requests in a day, each request not containing more than 200,000 records?

Terms like this will make the service useless for apps that make such requests based on who the user's data.

I can invest in freemium service also, if anyone knows other provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Openstreetmap's term doesn't allow heavy querying either

You could use [MapQuests version of Nominatim,](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim) it provides a free API to OpenStreetMaps Geo data [without the usage limits](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Usage_Policy).

http://devblog.mapquest.com/2011/11/17/no-preset-limit-on-free-map-api-transactions/

Comment: Look promising!  Does it allow batch realtime processing?

Comment: Don't think so.. think you'd have to fire off individual requests!

Comment: But you most closely answered my question!

Comment: They actually have limit of 15,000 requests per day - https://developer.mapquest.com/plans

Comment: https://developer.mapquest.com/plans now says 15,000 per month.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/). It offers a web service for geocoding, though that is also rate-limited. However, if you exceed the acceptable usage of the service, you can download the data and set up your own server.

For geocoding, you probably want to look at setting up your own [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) server. See e.g. here for installation instructions: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation

Comment: +1 for OSM. I've tried to write a geocoder against OSM data before - didn't know Nominatim existed! (would've saved some time...)

Answer (score 1):

*"Does that mean I can only make 24 requests in a day, each request not containing more than 200,000 records?"*
Yes, that's exactly what it means. The Bing Maps spatial data services API is a batch service - it's not intended for real-time geocoding of data by end-users but rather if you want to geocode the new records inserted into a database table as an hourly scheduled job, say (hence why 24 requests a day).

Also note 3.2 d) - you can only store geocodes from Bing Maps geocoding service if you're then going to display the results on a Bing Map.

For alternative providers, I recommend you look at one of the geonames web services: http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html
The appropriate service really depends on what level of accuracy you want to geocode to, and what source of data you want. Note that geocoders vary in quality a lot and a service that works well with US addresses, say, may be awful in Europe.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for the vote down too.....
@alastair, how long is the lag time before you get a response say you're geocoding 300 address based on your experience?

Comment: @William - it can vary immensely, but I've personally experienced response times of up to 24hours. I'm pretty sure that Microsoft don't guarantee any sort of SLA either, so I wouldn't recommend the use of the Bing SDS in any kind of customer-facing app. Having said that, it's the only free (depending on how you use it) service that I know of that can geocode that kind of volume of data.

Comment: Thank you for your info. Do you know any service that charge and can provide that level of capability?

Comment: Should also mention that the time taken to get the response doesn't really seem to relate to the volume of data you're geocoding - a batch containing 100,000 records may get processed faster than a batch containing only 10 - the limiting factor is that you are placed in a queue so it depends how many other users are in front of you at the point you submit the job.

Comment: Depends on what country you are interested in. If I'm only interested in geocoding addresses in the UK, say, I'd go to a service from the Ordnance Survey, but that's no good anywhere else!

Comment: I'm in the US. Well..good to know, in case I need to startup in UK in the future : )

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim via HTTP request.  No issues so far, been off line a couple of times but nothing major.  Jim

Comment: Do they have a usage limit on how often, and how many you can request?

Comment: None that I found when searching and they haven't blocked me not even once.  In the last 24 hours I've made 22,000 + request without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try [geocodefarm's api](http://www.geocodefarm.com/). It allows for up to 100,000 requests per day. They don't do batch geocoding, but I'm pretty sure you can setup a foreach loop to do batch for you. If you contact them, they allow upgrading higher, but for higher fees of course. Not sure if you're willing to pay, but the prices are really affordable.

~ Alex